# solution to use pug with ajax to rending a dynamic table

Tags: jquery, ajax, pug

I have a json file on the server, my intention is to render a table according to the contents in the json file, which contains various links.

So, the pug file looks like:

```
script.
        $.getJSON("/db/url.json", function(json) {
            console.log('DEBUG: from PUG: 1st URL in the JSON: ' + json[0].urls[0].url)
        });

table.table
  thead
    tr
      th.bg-primary.text-center.font-weight-bold.text-white(scope='col' colspan=7)
          a.btn.btn-primary(data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseExample' role='button' aria-expanded='true' aria-controls='collapseExample')
            | Section-1
  tbody.collapse.show(id='collapseExample')
    tr
       // Table contains will be got from the url.json file
```

The url.json file could be loaded quite well. But I'm frustrated on how to use this json to populate the tables in the pug template. Could you provide any idea?

The jason file look like:

```
  {
    "name": "Section-1",
    "desc": "Section-1",
    "urls": [
      {
        "name": "Google",
        "url": "http://www.google.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "xxx",
        "url": "http://10.182.44.97/"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already have the data in the callback of `getJSON`, you can then, in the same callback, continue to use jQuery to dynamically populate the DOM and insert data into your table

Comment: is it possible to insert into the pug? because the pug structure is more neat and easier to handle.

Comment: @Solaris_9 If I understand your situation correctly: you have the json file on the server side, then why not just pass the json data into pug directly via express [app.render](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render) instead of using ajax.
you can try something like `app.render('index.pug', { data: your-json }`

Comment: I will study this option and get back to you. Thanks for your suggestion.